# How centroid is getting linked to one Parcel if centroid is lying on boundary of adjacent parcel

Tags: geometry, fme-form, fme-transformer

In my case there Parcel is who is supplier and building centroid is requestor in SpatialRelator of FME Script. You can see black round in one below picture. So even if centroid is falling on adjacent parcel boundary it got link of one parcel. How come ? why it's not gone for one to many matches ?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what spatial predicates are you using in the SpatialRelator transformer. If it's *Within-Supplier* or *Contains-Supplier* then I would think a point on the exact boundary wouldn't match.

But if you also turn on *Intersects-Supplier* or *Touches-Supplier* then it would also get that point as a match.

The other possibility is that it really doesn't fall inside, but only by a very tiny amount that it's not easy to see; especially when there's not a vertex at that point on the line of the parcel.

What you could do to test that is add a transformer like an AnchoredSnapper and use the Vertex Snapping option. If the point gets snapped to the line, then you can compare its before and after coordinates to see how much it moved.

If it doesn't get snapped then you can assume its already on the line exactly and that the SpatialRelator should find it with the correct predicates.

The LeftRightSpatialCalculator would also help because it would tell you if the point is to the left or right of the line.

These aren't transformers that you need to add to your overall workflow, just ones that you can use as a one-off test to assure yourself that the FME results are (or aren't) correct.

Comment: Attached screenshot of SpatialRelator configuration.

Comment: Yeah, so I'm not sure that a point on the line itself counts as an intersect. So add the Touches option I suggested and see if that helps. Another thing I do is create a small example where I know for sure it ought to be exactly on the line. For example, I use the Creator to create a line from 0,0 to 10,0 and another Creator to create a point at 0,5. Now I know for sure the point is exactly on the line and can experiment with the correct settings to use to make sure it is found as a relation.

Comment: LeftRightSpatialCalculator this transformer give left as output means that point most relevant to left side parcel right ?

Comment: Yes, although it depends on the direction of the line. Is it clockwise or anti-clockwise?